# Discrete Mathematics, combinatorics?

Tags: combinatorics

> Consider the equation
> $$x_1+x_2+x_3+...+x_8=71$$
> where $x_1,x_2,...x_8\in\Bbb N$.
>
> (a) $x_i \ge 1$ for all $1\le i\le 8?$

my working out:

let $y_i=1-x_i$. Since $x_i\ge 1$ then we see that $y_i$ is non negative. Rewriting our equation we get

$(1-y_1)+ (1-y_2)+ ...+(1-y_8)=71$

Where am I suppose to go from here top find the number of solutions?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: If $y_i=1-x_i$ and $x_i\geq1$, then $y_i\leq0$

Comment: If you are trying to find the number of solutions, see the Stars and Bars method.

Comment: Assuming that you are trying to find the number of solutions, see [this article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/) and                                                               [this 2nd article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)).

Comment: yes, im trying to find the number of solutions! I forgot to add that

Comment: Hint : If $$x_1 + \cdots + x_8 = 71$$ and $$x_1, \cdots, x_8 \in \Bbb{Z^+}$$ and $$y_i = x_i  - 1,$$ then $$y_1, \cdots, y_8 \in \Bbb{Z_{\geq 0}} ~~\text{and}~~ y_1 + \cdots + y_8 = 63.$$  Typically, the Stars and Bars articles are geared to solutions involving **non-negative** integers, which includes **zero**.  The first article that I cited, in a previous comment, gives examples that reflect adjusting the variables (for example from $x_i$ to $y_i$).

Answer (score 1):

This expression can be written like $y_1+y_2+y_3+...+y_8 =63$ where $y_i \geq 0$ . Notice that we obtained $y_i$ by reducing $1$ from each component so we reduced $ 8\times 1 =8 $ from the total sum.

Then , we should use combination with repetition formula https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination ,so $C(63+8-1,63)=2186189400$ is the answer..